# Shortcut links to Ember.js Data components for create/update/delete actions

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

Create/update/delete actions call Ember Data Model, Store, Transaction, and Adapter. I would like to know where their code sources are found, i.e. shortcut links to Ember Model, Store, Transaction, and Adapter code.

Answer (score 0):

Links and useful functions for create/update/delete:

1. [Ember Data Model](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/packages/ember-data/lib/system/model/model.js#L28)

   save
2. [Ember Data Store](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/packages/ember-data/lib/system/store.js#L93)

   scheduleSave, flushSavedRecords, commit
3. [Ember Data Transaction](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/packages/ember-data/lib/system/transaction.js#L88)

   commit
4. [Ember Data Adapter](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/packages/ember-data/lib/system/adapter.js#L93)

   save, commit